# Can Safari tabs from an iOS device be recovered from an iTunes backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

Before upgrading from an iPhone 12 Pro to an iPhone 13 Pro, I backed up my phone in iTunes.

However, my safari tabs did not transfer over to the new phone and I lost them all (even though Safari was checked in iCloud settings).

Is there a way to access my browsing history from my previous iTunes back up?
Or do I have to restore the device from iTunes to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

If your backup was made with encrypted backups enabled, then it should include the browsing history including your Safari tabs.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205220

I'm a developer for one of the third party apps that can read iTunes backups, Decipher Backup Browser - that app can read the safari history and tabs from an encrypted iTunes backup.

Comment: It was not encrypted. If it's not, is the data just not accessible?